# Как сделать подчеркивание цветов в color highlighter в sublime text 3?

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Для обычных свойств css, так и для переменных scss(они вообще не подсвечиваются).
Особенно отвратительно выглядят темные цвета, можно как-то в настройках поменять удобное отображение?

[image: снимок]

Comment: [**Color Helper**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ColorHelper) вместо Color Highlighter попробуйте. См. GIF в пакете, там, на мой взгляд, более удачно подсвечиваются цвета. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Color Helper отлично справляется с задачей